# how to hide list column name?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, and I am using publishing portal template. I am using Insert Data View function from SharePoint Designer 2007 to insert a list created in parent site to a child site. Now the list content displays correctly.

My question is, how to hide the column name (displayed at the top of list content rows) in my child site (I want to show the list rows only, no need to show the list column name)?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide it using CSS. You must a content editor web part and put the correct css style to hide it (display: none).

Comment: Any sample code?

Comment: In the css configure in your site add this rule:

table.ms-menutoolbar { display: none; }

Comment: Question answered!